# Closing an iframe with a link

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I'm trying to set up a feature whereby a link on my main page will open a 'popup' window and another link in the popup window will open up an iframe. From within the iframe I have a 'close' button which will close the iframe and return to the popup window. However I cannot get the iframe to open again if i click on the link within the popup window. All I get is an empty frame.

Here's a link to exactly what is happening: http://afhxvzdf.tumblr.com

On the iframe's page I have these two codes which I used for closing the iframe.

```
       <script>
function openFrame(frm) {
        for( i=1; i<3; i++) document.getElementById('linka'+i).style.display="none"';
        var openFrame = document.getElementById(frm);
        if ( openFrame.style.display == 'none' ) {
                    openFrame.style.display == 'block';
        } 

        else {
                    openFrame.style.display == 'block'
        }
}
    </script>
```

and the link to close the iframe:

```
        <a href="javascript: window.parent.document.getElementById('linka').style.display='none'" title="close">Close iframe</a>
```

I'm not very familiar with javascript whatsoever so I'm baffled. Any help would be very appreciated, thanks!

Comment: It seems to work fine for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: Google Chrome. It works fine until I close the iframe via the link and try to reopen it without refreshing whatsoever. I would get this empty box instead http://s9.postimg.org/f9ok191rh/Screen_Shot_2016_01_30_at_2_25_52_am.png

edit: okay I found out it works on Safari. Any reason why it wouldn't work in Chrome?

Comment: Are you trying to create some kind of clickjacking script here?

Comment: Not sure what clickjacking means, but I googled and -- No? I'm just trying to make popup contents and because of the way themes are made in tumblr, using iframes is less complicated than jamming thousands of words on a single sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works fine if you close the popup by clicking on the normal page.
So i think you shouldn't make the close button in the iframe.

Another solution would be to force a refresh by clicking on the link to open the popup.

Comment: I added force refresh on the 'click on link to close iframe' link and it solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: I had the same issue at the intranet page in my work. If you closed the iframe it was closed until the page will be refreshed. I think this is exactly the same problem. So if you would make a close button on the "real" page and not on the iframe it should correctly "hide" the iframe. This maybe would be the best option. But you can try to force a refresh on each time you click on the button "link to the iframe" maybe with this script  `javascript:history.go(0)`